# Configuration error authentication mode="Windows"

Tags: asp.net, iis

Buen día,

Al momento de publicar mi aplicación ASP.net en el servidor, me despliega el siguiente error,

**Configuration error 
authentication mode="Windows"**

Esto es parte de mi Web.config

```
<system.web>
   <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

Y estoy usando IIS7.

¿[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Comment: No se si le ayudar, pero prueba "<authentication mode="None" />" (de https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

El error hace referencia que el sitio en el IIS no esta correctamente creado.

Si realizas la implementacion en un `Application` sobre el `Default` web site debes asegura que este correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

veras que el icono que muestra es diferente a la de una carpeta, esta es de color amarillo, mientras que el application el como un mundo con documentos.

A este puede asignarle un `Application Pool`

Tambien podrias convert una carpeta en application

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Sino deberias crear un sitio separado al cual le asignes un puerto especifico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas crear un directorio virtual nuevo para tu app:

**Start->All program-mes->Administrative tools->Internet Information service-> Select Server name->Web Site->Default Web site-> right click ->new->virtual directory**

Esto abrirá un wizard donde eliges la ruta de tu app y configuras los permisos.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314043111/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/robgruen/archive/2005/09/12/464196.aspx)

Comment: Que tal Gemasoft, algo que se me paso omitir es que ya tengo creado mi directorio virtual,

Comment: Si, pero lo creaste como directorio, no como app.